# wininet.dll missing

Tags: windows-7, dll

I was installing an updated version of .net framework on a machine which had to restart but now the machine keeps telling me that all these applications cannot run due to a dll file called wininet.dll is missing. I was working remotely and I think the internet connection dropped out at some stage so not sure if that caused it or what happened. I cannot go to a restore point as someone turned the machine on before I could restore it, it is not in the recycle bin and I cannot find it if I run a search one the machine. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Someone "turning the machine on" shouldn't prevent you from using System Restore-- what happened when you tried? Have you tried running SFC?

Comment: I was working on the machine on Tuesday and could not look at it again until Thursday and because they turned the machine on Wednesday there was no restore point left from the day before. What is SFC?

Comment: @techie007 thanks running a SFC /scannow worked and fixed the issues for me. If you put it into an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running Windows' [System File Checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) utility, as it's intended to restore overwritten and missing system files.

From `SFC /?`:

> Scans the integrity of all protected system files and replaces
>   incorrect versions with correct Microsoft versions.

Usually you want to use `SFC /ScanNow`.

Answer (score 0):

Go search for a copy of wininet.dll online, or grab one from another computer, then throw it in your C:\Windows\system32 folder. Make sure it isn't a virus, because DLLs can be viruses too.

Comment: Are there any potential problems using dlls from other machines? I have found the dll from http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?wininet but how do I know what version I need